# Network card that came bundled with a space war game

Tags: network, identify-this-software, identify-this-card

In the 90s, before everything was networked, you had to buy a Network Interface Card as an expansion card for your PC.  One brand came with a bundled game where you piloted a space ship and fought other people on your shiny new network.

Can anyone remember the NIC and/or the game?

Comment: Mind to add what kind of PC? IBM, or Mac or something else? Also, what exactly you call a NIC in this case? Last but not least what country the sale took place/was originated, maybe naming the shop/seller?

Comment: The NIC was probably an NE1000/NE2000 that Novell produced. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NE1000

Comment: Sorry, I thought PC would cover it.  I meant a IBM PC clone

Comment: @KevinWhite  spot on the money!  It was the NE2000 I remember

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The description of space combat over a network also matches [NetWars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetWars), which was bundled with Novell DOS and Personal Netware.

Comment: Playing games, at work, "testing the network"    Halcyon days :)

Comment: Yes, Descent was bundled with the 3Dfx Voodoo.

Answer (score -1):

asteroids?  Was it spacecraft that you could spin, accelerate, slow down, and shoot, while asteroids were approaching?